# FIX 4.2 and ExecReportAck

Tags: quickfix

we have a counterparty that implement FIX 4.2 standard to send executionReport messages (35=8).

In their specifications, they need a message in order to check the correct transmission. The strange thing is that the message type is "BN", that's not in 4.2 specs.

I've implemented a method in order to send such kind of message, and all works fine, but the quickfix put this message into the errorlog.

There is a way to tell quickfix to exclude from errorlog these "BN" messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try editing the DataDictionary. I would create a new file.   And set the DataDictionary location to the new file in your quickfix config file.

In the XML file for the data dictionary add an additional Message Type that to match what your counter party is sending you.

In the Message Type field:

```
<field number="35" name="MsgType" type="STRING">
```

add a line something like this:

```
<value enum="BN" description="MESSAGE_TYPE_NAME" />
```

where MESSAGE_TYPE_NAME is the correct description

Then add a type

```
 <message name="ExecutionReportAck" msgtype="BN" msgcat="app">
  <field name="OrderID" required="Y"/>
  <field name="SecondaryOrderID" required="N"/>
  <field name="ClOrdID" required="N"/>
  ...
 </message>
```

Comment: I've edited the DataDictionary and insert these lines:  '<message name='ExecutionReportAck' msgcat='app' msgtype='BN'>
   <field name='ExecID' required='Y' />
   <field name='ExecAckStatus' required='Y' />' but without success.
  </message>

Comment: Not sure but may adding the following in the configuration file helps          ValidateUserDefinedFields=N

Comment: I thought about that, but as MsgType is not a UserDefinedField I don't think that will work

Comment: Thanks very much for your edited post! I had forgotten to add the enum='BN' line in the DataDictionary file.